# Libraries for obtaining usage data and connection speed for a specific period of time

Tags: java, c++, python, desktop-application, bandwidth

Am getting to do a project that consists of a cross-platform(windows, linux, mac) native desktop app that measures a user's data usage (in KB, MB, GB) and the link connection  speed(in kbps or mbps) for either wi-fi, ethernet or 3G modem connectivity options.

Am confortable with java, python, C++ in that order. Done some googling, but i wasn't satified. So am looking for any recommendations on libraries, frameworks in any of these languages that will enable me accomplish the above task.  Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

The task can be split into two parts:

1. Gathering the data and storing them somewhere.
2. Presenting them to the user.

Often [RRDtool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) (RRD = round-robin database) is used for both parts. It depends on your requirements, you could for example use RRDtool to gather the data you need and them use some Python or Java RRD library for displaying the results.

See also:

- [Java RRD library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561876/java-rrd-library)
- [rrd4j](https://code.google.com/p/rrd4j/)
- [PyRRD](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyRRD)

Comment: Thanks Petr Pudlák. I'll play with it as soon as i start the project.